# Как проверить значение переменной jQuery из формы?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, input

Вот кусок моей формы:

```
<div class="form-group">
  <label for="firstName">Firstname</label>
  <input id="first_name" name="first_name" type="text" class="form-control">
</div>
```

В скрипте при помощи jQuery я объявляю переменную `firstName` и инициализирую её значением из формы:

```
var firstName  = $("#first_name")
```

Сразу после этой строки я прекрасно могу увидеть значение переменной про помощи `alert(firstName.val());`, но затем **по нажатию кнопки** я вызываю функцию, в которую передаю эту переменную в качестве параметра.

```
mynamespace.MyFunc(firstName);
```

При попытке напечатать значение переменной на первой строке в теле функции, alert ничего вообще не выводит. Таким образом, код:

```
mynamespace.MyFunc(element) {
  alert(element.val());
}
```

ничего не вернёт.

Как мне проверить содержимое переменной *непосредственно в функции*?

Comment: "ничего не получается" - опишите "ничего" более подробно

Comment: @Igor, дополнил.

Comment: А можно целый кусок кода увидеть? А то у Вас странные методы изъяснения

Comment: Посмотрите нет ли исключений в консоли  Develooper Tools браузера.

Comment: прошу прощения, @Igor, дополнил, да не всё. Функция вызывается _по нажатию кнопки_. То есть элемент уже есть на странице.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Это так выглядит?

```js
var firstName = $('#first_name');

$('#button').on('click',function(){
  MyFunc(firstName);
});

function MyFunc(element) {
  if(element.val()!='')
  alert(element.val());
  else
  alert('Вы ничего не ввели в поле');
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="form-group">
  <label for="firstName">Firstname</label>
  <input id="first_name" name="first_name" type="text" class="form-control">
</div>

<button id="button">press</button>
```

Comment: Нереально круто. Я мечтал именно о таком объяснении! Спасибо.

Answer (score -2):

Функция [jQuery](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery/) возвращает не DOM element, а коллекцию элементов, соответствующих заданному селектору. Поэтому и работать с ее результатом следует как с коллекцией. Рекомендуется использовать функцию [each](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/).

```
firstName.each(function() { mynamespace.MyFunc(this); });
```

Comment: Читайте для начала вопрос, там в `firstName` не `class`, а `id`, в таком случае перебор через `.each()` не нужен.

Comment: @CbIPoK2513, чтобы быть точнее, в примере из вопроса можно обойтись без .each() потому, что в MyFunc используется функция, которая возвращает значение первого элемента коллекции (val). Может быть, это именно то что и имел в виду автор кода. Но может быть что этот нюанс не был очевиден, и в коде ошибка.